# configurar web.config para recuperar contraseña

Tags: c#, login, asp, web.config

puede que la pregunta sea muy basica pero no logro descifrar y no encuentro informacion sobre el tema. tengo mi sitio web con autenticacion implementada usando los controles de c#. en mi archivo de configuracion ya se sabe cual es el sitio de login, y cuál es el default

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
        </authentication>
```

cómo configuro el web.config para que al entrar al sitio resetpassword.aspx no me dirija al login, sino que haga lo que necesito? ya intente con membershipprovider, pero me genera demasiados errores de carga, asi que mejor lo dejo como está

otra opcion puede ser que en el sitio login oculte el control loginform, y muestre el resetpassword, pero no se si es seguro?

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu página resetpassword.aspx no debe requerir autorización, porque obviamente alguien que olvidó su password no puede entrar a una página protegida para resetearlo.

Para quitar la protección a una página en particular, en el web.config debes poner lo siguiente

```
<configuration>
   <!-- OTRAS CONFIGURACIONES -->

   <location path="resetpassword.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
           <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Donde en path colocas la ruta de la página, que en el ejemplo anterior se encontraría en la raiz del sitio